# Dapper to map custom column name from sql server using asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dapper

I have the below return type

```
 private class ChangeMetadata
        {
            public long SetId { get; set; }
            public string EntityId { get; set; }
            public string EntityType { get; set; }
            public User User { get; set; }
            public EntityChangeType EntityChangeType { get; set; }
            public HistoricalChangeDto Change { get; set; }
        }

public class HistoricalChangeDto : EntityDto
    {
    public DateTime ChangeTime { get; set; }
    }

public class EntityDto
    {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    }
```

In this DTO I have User and HistoricalChangeDto and below sql query to return the data

```
SELECT 
      [a0].[EntityChangeSetId] AS [SetId], 
      [a0].[EntityId], 
      [a0].[EntityTypeFullName] AS [EntityType], 
      [a0].[ChangeType],
      [a0].[Id] AS [EntityChangeId],
      [a0].ChangeTime,  
      [a2].[Id],   
      [a2].[EmailAddress],  
      [a2].[IsInvitedAdvisor],  
      [a2].[JobTitle], 
      [a2].[Name], 
      [a2].[Surname], 
      [a2].[TenantId], 
      [a2].[UserName]  
    FROM 
      [AbpEntityChanges] AS [a] 
      INNER JOIN [AbpEntityChanges] AS [a0] ON [a].[EntityChangeSetId] = [a0].[EntityChangeSetId] 
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
          [a1].[Id], 
          [a1].[UserId] 
        FROM 
          [AbpEntityChangeSets] AS [a1] 
        WHERE 
          [a1].[Reason] <> 'Content Pack Download'
          OR ([a1].[Reason] IS NULL)
      ) AS [t] ON [a].[EntityChangeSetId] = [t].[Id] 
      INNER JOIN [AbpUsers] AS [a2] ON CASE WHEN [t].[UserId] IS NULL THEN 8074 ELSE [t].[UserId] END = [a2].[Id] 
    WHERE 
      [a].[EntityTypeFullName] = 'LegalRegTech.Assessments.Assessment' 
      AND [a].[EntityId] = 10942
```

`[a0].[Id] AS [EntityChange_Id]` Should map to `HistoricalChangeDto.Id` and `[a0].ChangeTime` should map to `HistoricalChangeDto.ChangeTime`

And User Dto has its own property

I have written this dapper query

```
var assessmentChangeMetadataQueryResult  = await connection.QueryAsync<ChangeMetadata, HistoricalChangeDto, User,ChangeMetadata>(assessmentChangeMetadataQuery,
                (changeMetadata,historicalChange,user) =>
                {
                    changeMetadata.User = user;
                    changeMetadata.Change = historicalChange;
                    return changeMetadata;
                },
                splitOn: "EntityChangeId,Id");
```

[image]

The `ChangeTime` is mapped to the `HistoricalChangeDto.ChangeTime`, however `[a0].[Id] AS [EntityChangeId]` is not mapped to `Id`

Answer (score 0):

try changing HistoricalChangeDto.Id to HistoricalChangeDto.EntityChangeId

```
  public class HistoricalChangeDto
    {
        public long EntityChangeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChangeTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I can't change it, since the Id is common in all the entities and it has been inherited from a common DTO who holds the id property. Updated the code

Comment: how about changing your sql query? Do you need column [a2].[Id]

Comment: Yes I do, it is related to the id of the User, so need that

Comment: you need to add `public long EntityChangeId { get; set; }` into your `HistoricalChangeDto` class and then `[a0].[Id] AS [EntityChange_Id]` Should mapped to `HistoricalChangeDto.EntityChangeId`